# RecyclerView adapter showing more images than it should be

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView adapter that inflates another layout (`child_layout.xml`) into the main layout (`main_layout.xml`).

Here is the RecyclerView adapter:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static Context context;
    private List<Message> mDataset;

    public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<Message> myDataset) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnCreateContextMenuListener, View.OnClickListener {
        public TextView title;
        public LinearLayout placeholder;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            view.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);

            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            placeholder = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.placeholder);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.main_layout, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder((LinearLayout) view);

        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Message item = mDataset.get(position);

        holder.title.setText(item.getTitle());

        int numImages = item.getImages().size();

        if (numImages > 0) {
            View inflater = LayoutInflater.from(holder.placeholder.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.child_layout, holder.placeholder, false);
            ImageView image = (ImageView) inflater.findViewById(R.id.image);
            Glide.with(context)
                .load("http://www.website.com/test.png")
                .fitCenter()
                .into(image);
            holder.placeholder.addView(inflater);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

}
```

Here is `main_layout.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/placeholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is `child_layout.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is, as I scroll through my app, some of the views are showing 2+ images (when the `child_layout` only has one `ImageView`):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4n2I.png

Why does this happen? Why do some views show more than one image when it should only be showing one?

Comment: Why do you use two separate layouts and do not merge them into one ? what is that you're trying to achieve ?

Comment: I plan to later add a conditional that loads a different child layout depending on the number of images. As far as I know, inflating the child layout this way is the only method I've come up with.

Comment: if you want to use different layouts for each row based on some conditions, you should use `getItemViewType` method, the second parameter of `onCreateViewHolder` returns the result of `getItemViewType` method so that you could inflate different layouts in respect to the row position.

Comment: I'll give that a shot. That might actually be a better alternative.

Answer (score 2):

`onBindViewHolder` is meant for binding data to the view you created in `onCreateViewHolder` (hence the name). You shouldn't inflate a new view every time in `onBindViewHolder`, because that takes away the large benefit of a `RecyclerView`, namely view recycling. What's causing the issue currently is that you inflate and add a child to a main view every time `onBindViewHolder` is called. This method can be called multiple times for a single view, meaning you're adding new child views every time it's called. You can fix this by only inflating the child view once inside `onCreateViewHolder`. Your conditional check in the binding suggests you don't want it visible at all times. What you could do there is call `setVisibility` on the child view to hide it if no images are present.

Comment: If I put `View child = LayoutInflater.from(holder.placeholder.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.child_layout, holder.placeholder, false);` into `onCreateViewHolder`, how do I refer to `placeholder`?

Comment: You don't need the placeholder in `onCreateViewHolder`. If you need a reference to the context for the layout inflater, just use `parent.getContext()`. By the way, I'm curious: why don't you put the `child_layout` inside the `main_layout`? As far as I can tell, you only ever use one `ImageView`, making the two seperate layouts a bit redundant. Unless I'm missing something of course.

Comment: Can you give a code example of how you would modify my code? And I plan to later add a conditional that loads a different child layout depending on the number of images.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, I don't think what you suggested would work completely. I plan to later inflate a different layout depending on the number of images (`child_layout_1` if 1 image, `child_layout_2` if 2 images, etc). That would require checking for the number of images within `onBindViewHolder`, no?

Comment: In that case, it becomes a bit more complex. If the images should just be displayed below the main layout, you can use different view item types and basically flatten the hierarchy inside the adapter. If you need some form of wrapping (i.e. each main layout also displays something below the children), it might become necessary to write a custom solution to manage the child layouts.